# Convert String (Json) to Rest Assured Response

Tags: java, json, httpclient, httpresponse, rest-assured

I have a `JSON` body as Java `String`. I would like to convert this `String` to `RestAssured Response`.  Is this possible?

Or

Is it possible to convert apache `HttpResponse` to `RestAssured Response`

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity entity = new org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity(body);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I'd like to convert `httpResponse` to `RestAssured Response`

Answer (score 0):

The `Response` Javadoc says "The response of a request made by REST Assured.". So, no I don't think its possible. I would make the request with `RestAssurred` anyway, I find it easier.

Reference: http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.2.3/com/jayway/restassured/response/Response.html

Comment: Problem is I'm getting `handshake_failure` error even after upgrading my `RestAssured` version to 3.0.1 which is the latest and claims to have fixed that issue. I still see it though. That's why I'm using `HttpResponse`

Comment: @user1629109 can you update your question with the full stacktrace of that error? Or post a new question for it? Sounds like that is the problem you really want to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what I'm trying to solve https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/548 . RestAssured lacks SNI support. So I'm getting handshake failure error when I try to connect a server that has SNI implemented. But Apache HttpClient works like a charm